# Access violation when calling the Zebra printer API

Tags: java, jna

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x5f0c25fe, pid=14780, tid=11168
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ZBRGraphics.dll+0x25fe]
```

I keep getting this error when using the Zebra printer DLL in Java program.

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZBRGraphics zGraphics = ZBRGraphics.INSTANCE;

        String text = "Print this";
        byte[] textB = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        String font= "Arial";
        byte[] fontB = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        System.out.println(zGraphics.ZBRGDIDrawText(0, 0, textB, fontB, 12, 1, 0x0FF0000, 0));
    }
}

public interface ZBRGraphics extends Library {
    ZBRGraphics INSTANCE = (ZBRGraphics) Native.loadLibrary("ZBRGraphics", ZBRGraphics.class);

    int ZBRGDIDrawText(int x, int y, byte[] text, byte[] font, int fontSize, int fontStyle, int color, int err);
}
```

I have the DLL in `C:\Windows\System32` and in my 32 bit Java . 
I'm using a 64 bit machine as my laptop for development.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with incorrect tags. This has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: There's no way we can really help you  here.  We know nothing of ZBRGraphics or what the DLL contains.  You should talk to their mailing/distribution list and ask for help with what this means since the error lies *solely* within that DLL.

Comment: Are you sure you have the parameters correct/in the correct order?

Comment: Hiya, it looks like you're attempting to interface with a Zebra card printer. More specifically, a ZXP1 or ZXP3. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my google-fu skills are any good, you appear to be interfacing with the Zebra printer's API. According to the "ZXP1 & ZXP3 Software Developers Reference Manual" (found [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeSmaha/zebra-printer-c/blob/e2fe39620096da09deb8b0a8520a7726f67b4a51/Doc/ZXP_1_3_SDKReferenceManual.pdf)), the Java mapping of the function is incorrect.

This is the actual C function prototype:

```
int ZBRGDIDrawText(
    int x,
    int y,
    char *text,
    char *font,
    int fontSize,
    int fontStyle,
    int color,
    int *err
)
```

As you can see, `err` is not an `int`, but a pointer to one. Also, since `text` and `font` are strings, you can just use a `String` as the Java type. Additionally, the API docs say that the return value is an `int` with either 1 for success or 0 for failure, meaning that you can use a `boolean` for ease of use.

The following Java mapping should be correct:

```
boolean ZBRGDIDrawText(
    int x,
    int y,
    String text,
    String font,
    int fontSize,
    int fontStyle,
    int color,
    IntByReference err
);
```

and you might use it like so:

```
IntByReference returnCode = new IntByReference(0);
boolean success = zGraphics.ZBRGDIDrawText(
    0,
    0,
    "Print this",
    "Arial",
    12,
    1,
    0x0FF0000,
    returnCode
);

if (success) {
    System.out.println("success");
} else {
    System.out.println("ZBRGDIDrawText failed with code " + returnCode.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cubrr. Last thing I want to ask, how about this one? int ZBRGetHandle(
HANDLE*hPrinter,
char*printerName,
int*printerType,
int*err) > the Handle part. What java class will I use for mapping? Is it PointerByReference?

Comment: Yeah, `PointerByReference` should work fine. If you're already including the `jna-platform` package as a dependency, you might as well use `WinNT.HandleByReference.`